# Numpad not working in 14.04

Tags: numpad

My numpad is not working on ubuntu 14.04. It used to work earlier and works in windows now. Please help

Comment: You'll need to provide some more info. What kind of keyboard are you using (make, model, laptop/desktop, etc.)?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 5547

Answer (score 0):

Make sure <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is activated.

Comment: I did that already